# I want to display in value in textbox, without clicking button. just update the value

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

I am just multiplying 10 and data(int),I want to display data in textbox, i don't want to update value by clicking button or something. I want trigger it by the text box event only. it automatically should update it.I am using vc++ 2010, windows form application.

this is my code:

private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
       unsigned long data = 10;
       unsigned long value;

       value=5*data;

       String^ str = value.ToString();

       textBox1->Text=System::String^ str;


 }
```

Comment: Please add the code till you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the result of the calculation in a different textbox to the one you are typing in.

As it is, when you put the new value in, it will fire the event and set it to 50 again. Which will do it again. And again. Forever. Or until the program crashes.

Comment: No, I am not getting any thing into that. It is blank when i run program. I dont want to display in textboxchange event.I want to update automatically. i tried event like lay out,VisibleChanged,Validated events. but its not working.

Comment: Your code at the moment just sets the value to 50 whenever the value changes. So if I type in "0", it will be immediately changed to 50. Then that will trigger it again to set it to 50, forever.  Why are you doing this anyway? Do you just want to make it readonly?

Comment: Ya.I am doing for assignment, But its not working in my side. I want to build GUI, which will do multiplication automatically without any button click.

Comment: Well you cannot do it in the TextChanged event, for the reason I gave.

Comment: K, But how to do it? m beginner to GUI. I mean which event in textbox to perceive that???

Comment: You can't have a system which says "every time it changes, change it" because it will loop forever. You need to have two different text boxes. Type in one, and show the answer in the other.